# Pass in parameter to handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js, handlebars.js

So I have a handlebars helper that is very simple -

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('selectRow', (rowIndex, selectedIds) ->
  console.log 'row index'
  console.log rowIndex
  console.log selectedIds
  isSelected = _.indexOf(rowIndex, selectedIds)
  if isSelected > -1 
    return 'class="row-selected"'
)
```

and I have this handlebars code -

```
<div class="title">{{ title }}</div>
<hr/>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    {{#each columns}}
    <th class="col-heading" data-heading="{{ this }}">{{ this }}</th>
    {{/each}}
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each rows}}
        <tr {{#selectRow @index selected }}>
          {{#each this}}
          <td>
            {{this}}
          </td>
          {{/each}}
        </tr>
      {{/selectRow}}
    {{/each}}

  </tbody>
</table>
```

the selected parameter is always undefined. If I add a {{ selected }} anywhere else, it shows an array, which, as you can see from below, it should -

```
data = @model.data()
selected = @model.get('selection').get('selected')
@$el.html(@tableContentsTemplate({
  columns: @model.get('columns')
  rows: data
  title : @model.get('title')
  selected: JSON.stringify(selected)
}))
```

How do I pass in the selected parameter correctly to my helper?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `selected` variable inside a Handlebars `each` loop, so I imagine `selected` is not in scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just a bit confused about how `_.indexOf` works. From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf):

> **indexOf** `_.indexOf(array, value, [isSorted])`
>
> Returns the index at which **value** can be found in the **array**, or *-1* if value is not present in the **array**.

So the array you're searching through, `selectedIds`, should be the first argument and the element you're searching for is the second. Perhaps you mean to say:

```
isSelected = _.indexOf(selectedIds, rowIndex)
```

or better (IMO):

```
isSelected = _(selectedIds).indexOf(rowIndex)
```

I generally find that using the `_()` function yields clearer code.

Also, shouldn't `{{#selectRow @index selected }}` be `{{selectRow @index selected}}`? A leading `#` should introduce a block but your helper is not written as a block helper.

Once both of the above issues have been fixed, sensible things seem to be happening for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pkVZc/1/